# When importing path from .env file I get two extra brackets added everywhere in the path variable?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, environment-variables

PATH_OLD = r'C:\Users\Bilal\Python\Task1\OlderVersionFiles\'
in my .env file.
I get the following:

```
"r'C:\\\\Users\\\\Bilal\\\\Python\\\\Task1\\\\OlderVersionFiles\\\\'"
```

instead of

```
r'C:\\Users\\Bilal\\Python\\Task1\\OlderVersionFiles\\'
```

on running the following code:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
result = os.getenv("PATH_OLD")
#Prints the correct path here
print(result)
dir_A_dict = dict()
directory_A = result
dir_A_files= [os.path.join(directory_A, x) for x in os.listdir(directory_A) if '.csv' in str(x)]
```

Gives the following error:

```
dir_A_files= [os.path.join(directory_A, x) for x in os.listdir(directory_A) if '.csv' in str(x)]
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: "r'C:\\\\Users\\\\Bilal\\\\Python\\\\Task1\\\\OlderVersionFiles\\\\'"
```

Comment: You can't use `r`-strings in an environment file. Note that in your first example, the value starts with a literal `r'...`.

Comment: but it gives no error when printing it? Only when I use it in ```[os.path.join(directory_A, x) for x in os.listdir(directory_A) if '.csv' in str(x)]``` does it give an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're feeding `os.listdir` a string that is **not** a valid directory name, so it complains.  You're trying to be too clever with your environment variable, it shouldn't be Python syntax.  Just be simple:

```
PATH_OLD = C:\Users\Bilal\Python\Task1\OlderVersionFiles\
```